# no default constructor exists for class in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have created a constructor, but why there is still have an error "no default constructor exists for class"?
I have searched for the answer to the question, but I am still not clear about this error. Can someone help me?

```
pragma once
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Date
{
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
public:
    Date(int newmonth, int newday, int newyear)
    {
        month = newmonth;
        day = newday;
        year = newyear;
    }
};
class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    Date birthDay;
    int score;
public:
    Student(string newname, Date newbirthDay, int score)
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In Student, you need to initialize the `Date birthDay` variable as part of the constructor's initialization list, otherwise it will attempt to initialize it with the default constructor, which does not exist. Example:

```
Student(string newname, Date newbirthDay, int score) : name(newname), birthDay(newbirthDay), score(score) {
}
```

In general, you should be using the initialization list (same for your `Date` class).

On an unrelated note, you should consider passing objects in by `const &`, i.e.:

```
Student(const string &newname, const Date &newbirthDay, int score) : name(newname), birthDay(newbirthDay), score(score) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor needs an empty parameter list, so in your case it'd be Date() or Student()